# How do I limit the width of a table or columns in org-mode PDF export?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, pdf

I'd like to format a table with a wide column nicely in PDF export from org-mode. Ideally it would be with a wrap on that column, but I can deal with a manual character or fraction of `\textwidth` for that column. I've tried a number of things, but I can't get it to change width. What do I need to do?

Sample:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width .6\textwidth
| Column                    | Wide Column                                        | Column   |
|---------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------|
|                           | <30>                                               |          | 
| Some stuff                | Lots and lots of stuff. Way too much. Like, a lot. |          |
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```org
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment longtable :align |l|p{10cm}|l|
|            | <30>                                               |        |
| Column     | Wide Column                                        | Column |
|------------+----------------------------------------------------+--------|
| Some stuff | Lots and lots of stuff. Way too much. Like, a lot. |        |
```

In this example the align table has three columns with `|` as a delimiter. The first and last are left justified (`l`). The middle one is a paragraph of width 10 cm (`p{10cm}`). Edit the align table in the `#+ATTR_LATEX:` line to match the number of columns you have.

Comment: Notably, `\pagewidth` and fractions of it don't work, sadly.