# Preventing Org-Mode PDF Tables from Running Off the Page

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Consider the following long org-mode table.

```
#+TBLNAME: Bitcoin
#+PLOT: title:"Bitcoin Return in 1,2, and 10 Years" ind:1 deps:(3 5 7) type:2d with:histograms set:"yrange [0:]" set:"style fill solid 1.0" exports:both
| Return Interval | $ for EV Calc | Probability in Year 1 | Dist1         | Probability in Year 2 | Dist2         | Probability in Year 10 | Dist3                          |
|-----------------+---------------+-----------------------+---------------+-----------------------+---------------+------------------------+--------------------------------|
| [0x, 0.2x]      |           0.1 |                  0.15 | WWWWWWW!      |                   0.2 | WWWWWWWWWW    |                    0.6 | WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW |
| [0.2x, 0.5x]    |          0.35 |                   0.1 | WWWWW         |                  0.15 | WWWWWWW!      |                   0.05 | WW!                            |
| [0.5x, 1x]      |          0.75 |                  0.15 | WWWWWWW!      |                  0.05 | WW!           |                      0 |                                |
| [1x, 2x]        |           1.5 |                   0.2 | WWWWWWWWWW    |                  0.05 | WW!           |                      0 |                                |
| [2x, 5x]        |           3.5 |                  0.25 | WWWWWWWWWWWW! |                  0.25 | WWWWWWWWWWWW! |                      0 |                                |
| [5x, 10x]       |           7.5 |                   0.1 | WWWWW         |                   0.2 | WWWWWWWWWW    |                      0 |                                |
| [10x, 100x]     |            55 |                  0.05 | WW!           |                   0.1 | WWWWW         |                   0.35 | WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW!             |
#+TBLFM: $4='(orgtbl-ascii-draw $3 0.0 1 50)::$6='(orgtbl-ascii-draw $5 0.0 1 50)::$8='(orgtbl-ascii-draw $7 0.0 1 50)
```

When exported to markdown format this long table shows up just fine and perfectly formatted; however, when I export to PDF I get something very ugly:

1. The table runs off the width of the page.
2. The table runs into the second page.

Here's what it looks like:

> [image]

**Question:** Is there a way to force this table to at least not run off the width of the page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put this code above your table:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment longtable :align |l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|
```

You can replace the `l` with `p{*cm}` where `*` can be any numeral as required to fit table to page. e.g.

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment longtable :align |p{3cm}|p{6cm}|l|l|l|l|l|l|
```

Please also see

- [Column width and alignment](https://orgmode.org/manual/Column-width-and-alignment.html#Column-width-and-alignment)
- [LaTeX specific attributes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/LaTeX-specific-attributes.html)
- [Org tables: Wrap all fields in column to a given size](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30871/18918)
- [Org-mode: How to fix table width to page width for dynamically generated tables?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41474/org-mode-how-to-fix-table-width-to-page-width-for-dynamically-generated-tables)
- [How do I limit the width of a table or columns in org-mode PDF export?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/27494/18918)

You would be able to solve your problem with above links.

> Easiest non-coder way around can be to "export file as HTML" and "print as PDF" from browser.

Comment: @Drew I have updated the answer. I am a non-coder and an org-mode noob and this is my 1st ever answer to any post. I have tried to explain the best possible way I can understand. Your suggestions and inputs are welcome.