# Org-mode: How to fix table width to page width for dynamically generated tables?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table

I am using dynamically generated table to create a tabulated to do list with various parameters using:

```
#+COLUMNS: %ITEM %SCHEDULED %DEADLINE
```

for more info see: [Org-Agenda export to dynamic Org-Table](https://www.reddit.com/r/orgmode/comments/8jbj75/tip_orgagenda_export_to_orgtable/)

**The exported table in PDF runs off the width of the page.**

**How to fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

Adding below code fixed it:

```
 #+ATTR_LATEX: :environment longtable :align |p{7cm}|l|l|
```

But each time I have to define variable e.g. 7cm by trial and error with pdf output.

Is there a more general solution which I can put in `#+ATTR_LATEX:` irrespective of the table?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment tabu
```

and remove the `:align` option. You might need to add

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tabu}
```

in the preamble of your org file. Note that `tabu` by default sets column width equal to the longest entry, so your exported table might go out of the page. If you face this problem, try using the `sideways` option

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :float sideways
```